# Pandas Python - Save dataframe without time part of date

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe which is imported from a file, into pandas, as part of a data analysis app.

```
date,value,cat
1/6/2000,5,a
2/6/2000,10,b
3/6/2000,15,c
```

I need to change the date format

```
import pandas.io.date_converters as conv
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('temp.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True, dayfirst=True)
print df
```

After running the above commands the dataframe looks like this in ipython

```
                 value  cat
date                                      
2000-01-06       5    a
2000-02-06       10   b
2000-03-06       15   c



df.to_csv('test.csv') # write dataframe to disk
```

After saving the file to disk and reading it back again, using textwrangler, ipython or any other editor the time format still appears.

```
                         value  cat
date                                      
2000-01-06 00:00:00       5    a
2000-02-06 00:00:00       10   b
2000-03-06 00:00:00       15   c
```

What is the most simplest way I can remove the time part of the date permanently.

Any simple solutions welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [date_format parameter](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas-dataframe-to-csv) of the `to_csv` method:

```
df.to_csv(filename, date_format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: I have a legacy system and am running version 0.9.0, can't upgrade till after project, so I will have to use a string replace or delete method many thanks.